# Ambiguity in method resolution and how to solve it

Tags: android, kotlin, byte-buddy

I'm creating a dynamic class from ByteBuddy that extends my own class `SupportMapFragment` that extends `Fragment` and using it in a layout. I want to redirect all method calls to this class to another fragment instance of Google's `SupportMapFragment`.

Here's my code:

```
        ByteBuddy()
            .subclass(SupportMapFragment::class.java)
            .method(ElementMatchers.any())
            .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.newInstance()))
            .make()
            .load(MainActivity::class.java.classLoader, AndroidClassLoadingStrategy.Injecting(file))
            .loaded
```

However method resolution does not work as I want. First thing is `clone()` method has an ambiguous delegation. I can (somehow) solve that by filtering methods at the method builder call using `ElementMathers`. However fragment methods also cannot be resolved

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot resolve ambiguous delegation of public void androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.onPrimaryNavigationFragmentChanged(boolean) to net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.MethodDelegationBinder$MethodBinding$Builder$Build@83edf592 or net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.MethodDelegationBinder$MethodBinding$Builder$Build@4349b5d2
```

I don't know why is there any ambiguity and how can I solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For redirection, you should not use `MethodDelegation`, rather use `MethodCall`. Method call allows you to invoke the instrumented method on another instance or field. This way, Byte Buddy does not even spend time trying to figure out a best interceptor - a rather expensive procedure - but directly invokes the method that is currently instrumented.

Comment: Thanks Rafael. I tried MethodCall however I can't see which API I can use to redirect all method calls to another instance.

Comment: Use `MethodCall.invokeSelf().on(...)`.

Comment: Thanks, now I'm starting to understand your rationale on this library. However now I get an `IllegalStateException: getLayoutInflater(Bundle) does not accept 0 arguments`, which from I understand is trying to map the `getLayoutInflater()` method to `getLayoutInflater(Bundle)`.

Comment: If you want to preserve the original arguments to the method, use `MethodCall.invokeSelf().on(...).withAllArguments()`.